# Body of code scanned continuously

Tags: javascript

Simple question, is there a definition/term that describes code or a language wherein the body of code is scanned continuously over and over again versus only when a function is called.

If so are there any special techniques that might not be obvious but I should keep in mind when coding/designing in these languages?

The language im coding in is JS but it is not being run by a browser, its being run by an iOS app that I load my work into.

TIA

Niko

Comment: Are you talking about a REPL environment?

Comment: Are you talking about "polling" vs functions or event-handlers?

Comment: I think I could have been clearer in explaining what is going on. For example if I have: var foo; foo=foo+1; in the body of the code (NOT wrapped in a function/event handler/if-lop) then foo will increment 4 times per second on-screen (eg in 3 seconds foo on screen will be 12). BUT if I say var foo=0; instead of just var foo; It will stay stuck at 1 and not increment further.

Answer (score 4):

> Simple question, is there a definition/term that describes code or a language wherein the body of code is scanned continuously over and over again versus only when a function is called.

Are you talking about "explicit vs implicit event loops?"

In 'normal' environments, you must explicitly write or call an "event loop" that reads messages (keys/mouse movements) and calls the event handlers. For CLIs (REPL), this is usually custom, but for GUIs, much of the boilerplate is handled by your platform. Usually, the last line of your code says `Events.run` or `while (!quit) { process_events }`

In other environments (i.e. the browser or Excel documents), you don't have an explicit event loop. You only write reactive code that says "on mouse movement" or "when this cell changes".  There actually is an event loop, but it's hidden deep beneath the platform, and you can't tinker with it.

> If so are there any special techniques that might not be obvious but I should keep in mind when coding/designing in these languages?

I don't think there's anything specific to "implicit event loops". But one thing to keep in mind for (single-threaded) event loop programming: You need to "give up the CPU" frequently to let events be pumped. In the bad old days, programs that were deep in thought (reading a file, or calculating) caused problems when dragged around the screen. The solution was to read the file or calculate in chunks, and yield to the event loop more often. (Today, the window moving is architected differently, so the problem doesn't show up there, but it can show up in other places.)

Comment: OP: I appreciate your explanation however Im afraid my experience with CS is not there yet. I am not too sure of the general idea of 'event loops'. I did learn some from what you shared but it did not quite answer my question. I did post an updated comment to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

these are event handlers which i think you are refering too.

Lets look at an example where the javascript waits to sense a click (ie the code is always going but once that thing happens it fires)

[link to where the example came from](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:red; margin:5px; cursor:pointer; }
  p:hover { background:yellow; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>First Paragraph</p>

  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
  <p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
<script>
    **$("p").click(function ()** {
      $(this).slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

if you see the click function (its bolded) is just wating for a paragraph element to be clicked on . So by using event handlers you can make it appear as though that code is constantly ready to go at a moments notice.

EDIT: comment on this because I think i may have miss understood what you were asking for or trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I think I could have been clearer in explaining what is going on. For example I have: var foo; foo=foo+1; In the body of the code (NOT wrapped in a function/event handler/if-lop) foo will increment 4 times per second on-screen (eg in 3 seconds foo on screen will be 12). AND if I say var foo=0; instead of var foo; It will stay stuck at 1 and not increment further.

Answer (score 0):

just a note, that kind of programming is very heavy from a memory perspective.  it's much better to have your program react to an event rather than continuously check a condition.

Javascript does have a setInterval function that basically runs a function over and over for a defined amount of time.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp